# What makes these words so special?

Tags: pattern, word-property

The following words share a special property or properties that make them very special. This list is complete. No other English words have what it takes to make this list:

**FUZIL

YUTZ

UNZIP

UNFIXT

PIXY

INFLUX

FUTZ

WIZ

UNFIX

PYX

PUTZ

FIZ**

What makes these words so special?

**HINT:**

> One of our members couldn't make it because no eligible partnerships could be formed.

Comment: Didn't think 80% of these were words at first

Comment: Does this have  anything to do with scrabble? they have very close scores.

Comment: @Marius you're on the right track.

Comment: You should call these ZYZZYVA words, due to the number of late letters in the alphabet.

Comment: @boboquack Did you know there's a community in CA named Zzyzx? Too bad it's not eligible for this list... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're

> the only English words made up of the standard pentomino names with a Scrabble score of at least 15 and no repeating letters.
>  [image]

Comment: If "Z" is a pentomino, then so is "S".

Comment: @MikeQ: How so? These are the standard names.

Comment: @Deusovi you have found the last piece of the puzzle! It's the only part that Marius hadn't yet discovered! :) +1

Comment: @wildBillMunson - oh, is this correct?

Comment: @Deusovi BINGO! :D Nice work!

Comment: @Deusovi I stand corrected - I didn't realize chiral pairs were counted as one type instead of two. Nice job!

Answer (score 7):

Not sure If I'm right here

> The [scrabble scores](http://www.thekatespanos.com/scrabble-score-calculator/) for the words are
>  FUZIL = 17
>  YUTZ = 16
>  UNZIP = 16
>  UNFIXT = 16
>  PIXY = 16
>  INFLUX = 16
>  FUTZ = 16
>  WIZ = 15
>  UNFIX = 15
>  PYX = 15
>  PUTZ = 15
>  FIZ = 15

Other things that might be useful or not

> The only vowels are U and I (not sure if Y is considered a vowel).
>  The consonants used are: F, L, N, P, T, W, (Y), X, Z (again not sure if I should put Y here).
>  None of the words have repeating letters (as [M Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48139/what-makes-these-words-so-special/48140?noredirect=1#comment146454_48140) says )

Conclusion.

> These are the only English words using the letters `f,i,l,n,p,t,u,w,x,y,z` without repeating them that have a score of at least 15 in scrabble.
>  not sure yet why these letters are special.

Comment: You're on the right track! +1 :D

Comment: And none of the words have repeated letters.

Comment: Hmm. But why these letters? You can achieve better scores from these letters with repetitions, eg FUZZY or UNWILFULLY. And you can get better scores with other letters, but without repetitions, eg QUARTZ or QUICK or WHIZ. And all of them are nicer words.

Comment: @MOehm I'm thinking about it now. I'm trying to transform them to numbers and other approaches to see what makes them special

Comment: @Marius n.b. I've just added a hint. :)

Comment: The missing word could perhaps be Wuz?

Comment: @BaileyM there are no missing words. The list is complete.

Comment: Then I misinterpreted the clue!